# How does rails implement before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm interested in how rails implement filters like `before_filter`.

But after reading the source code, I'm still confused.

I noticed that rails' framework maintains a `filter_chain`, and run the filters before the target method.

But, I do not understand an important process: how does rails capture a method calling?

I mean, for example, I have a class `Dog`, and set a `before_filter` to the method bark.

When I call `dog.bark`, rails should capture this calling in some way, and run its modified method instead.

However, I do not find such code in the source code.

Can anyone tell me the idea or point out where the code lies?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you set a `before_filter`, or any similar filter *(think `after_filter`, `around_filter`)*, you're doing so with either a [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html) or a [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html), lambda or block.

```
before_filter :bark
before_filter Proc.new { |k| k.bark }
```

The above appends the symbols or blocks to a stack [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L55), by calling [`set_callback`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L366). This builds the 'chain' you're referring to.

Each item in this 'chain' is an instance of the [`ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L85) class. This class knows

- The the method (Symbol) or block it must run *(ie. your class' `:bark` method)*
- The context which it must run within *(ie. your `Dog` class)*

The `Callback` instances are appended to a [`ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L85) in [`__update_callbacks`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L351).

When each `Callback` class is initialized, [`_compile_filter`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L229) is run to normalize the filter from the `Symbol`, `Proc`, lambda, or block into a common, callable format.

Finally, when the `CallbackChain` is run, it will call [`start`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/cal.lbacks.rb#L171) on each `Callback` instance, and **its at this point** that the filter is actually executed within the proper context.

---

It's important to point out that you would **not** create a filter like

```
before_filter dog.bark
```

this is going to execute `dog.bark` and pass it's return value to `before_filter` to be appended to the `CallbackChain`. The intention is to pass some sort of instruction on to `before_filter` for Rails to later execute for you. You would instead do something like

```
before_filter Proc.new { d = Dog.new; d.bark }
```

The code within the `Proc` is not executed. when the line above is run by Rails. Instead, Rails is being told to pass the `Proc` to the `CallbackChain`. The `Proc` is the 'instruction' you're passing on to Rails to execute at the appropriate time.

---

> how in the first place does rails know I have called :bark

As for this, let's say your `Dog` class is simply defined as

```
class Dog
  def bark

  end

  def eat

  end
end
```

*(Though this is a terrible example)*, you might want to have something like

```
before_bark :eat
```

This requires you define the `bark` callback, and then tell your `bark` method to run the related `bark` callbacks.

```
class Dog
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks

  define_callbacks :bark

  before_bark :eat

  def bark
    run_callbacks(:bark) { YOUR BARK CODE HERE }
  end

  def eat

  end
end
```

You can see how [`ActiveRecord::Callbacks`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb) does this.

This really is a bad example though because you can (and should) just call `eat` directly from  `bark`, but this should get the point across.

Comment: Thank you at first! But still confusion. You said 'Finally, when the CallbackChain is run...', and my question is exactly how does rails know the CallbackChain should be run? Say, if I set before_filter :eat to class Dog. Then when I call dog.bark, :eat should be run first. But, how in the first place does rails know I have called :bark?

Comment: Much clearer, but still a little confused. In your example, we redefine bark manually, but rails does it automatically by some code. I do not find where these codes lie. According to @harald, rails have modified each action in advance. I noticed 'attr_internal' in AbstractController::Base, is there magic happens?

Comment: For a class extending `ActionController::Base`, the `run_callbacks` is **[here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L16)**

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't capture method calls the way you describe. If you look at `AbstractController::Base.process` it will look up the method to be called for the dispatched action, run the filters and then call the actual method. In other words, your controller method is not called directly, but through this `process` method.

Comment: I got it, rails seems to use 'attr_internal' to change each method to a newly internal name and do all the thing with the new name?