# When is a before_filter executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the order of ActiveRecord callbacks and validations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969673/what-is-the-order-of-activerecord-callbacks-and-validations)

I comes from the background of Java. One thing I think very **weird** in Rails is that you can set up **call back functions like attributes** just under the class, such as `before_filter`.

```
class SomeController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter Proc.new {.....}
end
```

I don't really understand how it works. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174704/how-does-rails-implement-before-filter) which explains `before_filter` . I understand the flow of logic and it's just a method. But I still don't understand when will `before_filter` being executed to set up the callback chain.

Comment: `before_filter` is not provided by Ruby, but is instead provided by Rails (specifically ActiveRecord). I’ve edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: Those are ActiveRecord callbacks - this is not the same thing.

Comment: Nutshell: `before_filter` is run when the class is loaded.

Comment: @BradWerth Yikes you’re right. Too tired to comment. Also means ActiveRecord should be replaced by ActionController in my above comment.

Comment: Thank for all your comments. You said before_filter is run when the class is loaded. But I don't really get it. I found the source code from.https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d42d97d2e3f0bdef2163cc14daa181903e0b198d/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L92. My question is: I think `before_filter` is a instance method.(!?) How can I call a instance method within the class itself?

Comment: Or .. Did I get something wrong? they are actually `class method` !?

Comment: Thanks for you to help me realize it is a class method:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`before_filter` is not a Ruby feature, it is a class method provided by *Ruby on Rails* (the web framework) that you can use in your controllers to execute a piece of code before executing any action in your controller.

So, how does Ruby on Rails does that?

When you are defining a class in Ruby you are actually executing code, try this in irb:

```
class Hello
  puts "defining hello..."

  def greet
    puts "Hello there"
  end
end
```

You'll see that "defining hello..." gets printed in the terminal when you define the class. You have not instantiated any object, you just have defined a class, but you can execute any code in the middle of defining a class.

You know that you can define “class methods” and “instance methods”, and what's interesting is that you can call your class methods while you are still defining your class:

```
class MyClass
  def self.add_component(component)
    # Here @@components is a class variable
    @@components ||= []        # set the variable to an empty array if not already set.
    @@components << component  # add the component to the array
  end

  add_component(:mouse)
  add_component(:keyboard)
  add_component(:screen)

  def components
    @@components # The @@ gets you the class variable
  end
end

MyClass.new.components
=> [:mouse, :keyboard, :screen]
```

`def self.add_component` defines a class method that you can call while still defining your class. In this example `add_component` adds a keyboard to a list in a class variable, and the `def components` instance method (which is called on an instance of this class) access this class variable. The class method could have been defined in a parent class, and it would have worked the same. That example may be a little bit weird.

Let's do another example.

```
class RubyOnSlugsController
  def self.before_filter(callback)
    @@callbacks ||= []
    @@callbacks << callback
  end

  def execute_callbacks
    @@callbacks.each { |callback| callback.call() }
    return "callbacks executed"
  end
end

class MyController < RubyOnSlugsController
  before_filter Proc.new { puts "I'm a before filter!" }
  before_filter Proc.new { puts "2 + 2 is #{2 + 2}" }
end

controller = MyController.new
controller.execute_callbacks
```

will output:

```
I'm a before filter!
2 + 2 is 4
=> "callbacks executed"
```

Ruby on Rails does something similar (but quite more complex) with `before_filter`, and it makes sure that all callbacks you define with it are called before your normal controller methods.

I hope this clears things a little bit for you.

Comment: Very good explanation:) just some minutes ago, I misunderstanding `before_filter` as a instance method ... I have never thought  I can call the class method in defining the class :) It looks so amazing.

Answer (score 1):

The `before_filter` method itself gets run when your controller file is loaded (i.e. when your server starts). That means that the callback chain is set up as soon as the class is defined.

As for the callbacks that it sets up, the controller has a [`process`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L112) method which takes the name of an action (say, "index"), and calls the appropriate action method in [`process_action`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb#L166). The callbacks module overrides this method with an implementation that [runs the callback](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.11/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L16).

Comment: I never though I can execute Ruby code in the middle of Ruby class..