# before_filter {@amount =Amount.new}

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, before-filter

I am getting this error msg

> amount cant be blank

I want to create payment based on the amount created
I think my `before_filter {@amount=Amount.new}`, it does not assign the created amount to the payment method. so, my payment keeps giving the above error even after creating a new amount.

payment controller

```
before_filter {@amount =Amount.new}

def new
 @payment = Payment.new
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json { render :json => @order }
end
end

def create
  @payment = @amount.payments.build(params[:payment])      
  if @payment.save       
     if @payment.purchase
       render :action=> "success"
      else
        render :action=> "failure"
     end
  else
    render :action => "new" 
  end       
end
```

amount controller

```
def create
@amount = current_user.amounts.build(params[:amount])
respond_to do |format|
  if @amount.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_url, :notice => 'Amount was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :json => @amount, :status => :created, :location => @amount }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.json { render :json => @amount.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


def new
 @amount = Amount.new
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json { render :json => @amount }
 end
end
```

payment model

```
belongs_to :amount
```

amount model

```
 has_many :payments
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the guide manual, "the filter is not run in the scope of the controller" so `@amount` is actually setting a variable in some `ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback` and not your controller as you expected.

I think you may be able to fix this by putting `lambda` in front of your little chunk. If not, you'll have to define a `:set_amount` method and put your code there.

References:

[How does rails implement before_filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174704/how-does-rails-implement-before-filter)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Hope that helps.